Can I make Oracle not stop execution after a certain number of errors?
When doing a query to insert or update an Oracle table I get errors like "duplicated" when inserting, or "not found" when updating, but it looks like the number of errors has a limit. When that limit is reached, the query stops and the rest of the sentences are not executed.
We migrated from DB2 in mainframe and there is a parameter added as the first sentence in the query to allows any number of errors (SER MAXERRORS -1). Is there something similar in Oracle? Is this something that can be defined using the ALTER command?

Why not use a MERGE statement rather than worrying about inserts/updates erroring?

By default, a single error will immediately abort the SQL statement and roll back its work. If you are getting multiple row errors then you are programmatically reacting to each error with a decision to retry or move on. That has to be addressed programmatically. If you are using a client, then it's your client that's responsible for continuing to send additional statements despite having received an error, not Oracle itself.

If you're running these statements as a script in sqlplus then have a look at the WHENEVER SQLERROR command.

If you look at e.g. INSERT documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html, (same for UPDATE) there is an "error_logging_clause" part of the syntax.
